# Can I distort a bitmap image in Flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, image

what I would like to do is to take a loaded GIF file as a Bitmap, and then distort it by stretching and shrinking parts of it, so it would look like it got squished up against the screen.

I'm pretty sure that there's no easy way in Flash to go beyond scaling and shearing, but I wonder if there might be some simple techniques to accomplish this kind of effect.

By the way, I've also thought of pre-deforming the images in GIMP and saving them there, but I can't find a simple way to do it without learning their scripting language.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should check out the [`DisplacementMapFilter`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filters/DisplacementMapFilter.html). This tutorial should be a good start: http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2007/12/03/understanding-flash-displacement-map-filter/